# wxWidgets LINK issue in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to deal with `wxWidgets` for the first time, I tried to compile the below Hello World program:

```
/*
 * hworld.cpp
 */

#include "wx/wx.h" 

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:

    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

enum
{
    ID_Quit = 1,
    ID_About,
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Quit, MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(ID_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450,340) );
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
} 

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
: wxFrame( NULL, -1, title, pos, size )
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;

    menuFile->Append( ID_About, _("&About...") );
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append( ID_Quit, _("E&xit") );

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, _("&File") );

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText( _("Welcome to wxWidgets!") );
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    Close(TRUE);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox( _("This is a wxWidgets Hello world sample"),
                  _("About Hello World"),
                  wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this);
}
```

The compiler showed:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup    C:\Users\550\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\wxWidgitExample\wxWidgitExample\LINK
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\550\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\wxWidgitExample\Debug\wxWidgitExample.exe  1
```

What is the problem ? I use MS Visual Studio, I guess I need to use `#pragma` directive?

Comment: can you provide the commandline used to invoke the compile and link?

Comment: It is your first time with wxWidgets. I have used it for years and I should recommend you to try Qt too. You will see that Qt is far more cute ;-) Use QtCreator with Qt 4.8, try examples you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `wxDECLARE_APP(MyApp);` in the header file where MyApp is defined and `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);` in the cpp file where it is implemented. The description of these macros is avaliable in the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__rtti.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check your property sheets under Linker->System->SubSystem. Make sure the subsystem is Windows and not Console.

Answer (score 0):

That linker error you're getting usually indicates a mismatch in your project configuration settings between ansi vs unicode setup. If you're building your wxApplication with unicode enabled make sure `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined.

The entry point for a windows unicode application is `wWinMainCRTStartup` where as a non-unicode one has `WinMainCRTStartup` as its entry point. Normally wxWidgets should have that setup correctly for you when you built the framework.

To help troubleshoot your unresolved error I would try passing this switch to the linker when you attempt to build.

If you're example is not using unicode then use `/ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup`.

If you're example *is* using unicode then use `/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup`.